# You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=1.0.5000.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, pdf-generation, itext

I'm trying to include a html to pdf converter in my C# program for windows mobile.
I found Pdfizer.
I added a refence to Pdfizer.dll and included it with `using Pdfizer;`
Also I added a reference to itextsharp that is required for Pdfizer.

Pdfizer is correctly added and I can use many of its functions and classes but I can't use HtmlToPdfConverter.Run()

My code:

```
FileStream filePDF;
filePDF = File.Create(path + ".pdf"); // path is string
html2pdf.Open(filePDF);
html2pdf.AddChapter(@"Chapter name");
html2pdf.Run(html); // html is a string that contains html code
html2pdf.Close();
```

Problem is in line `html2pdf.Run(html);` It says:

```
Error   1   The type 'System.Uri' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

Definition of `Run` is

```
    public void Run(string html);
    public void Run(Uri uri);
```

I'm trying to use the `Run(string html)` option, but Uri is defined and visual studio says it is not referenced but yes it is.

I have  `using System;` that contains `Uri` class, indeed I use it in other functions and works properly.

What is the problem? Should I add a reference to `System, Version=1.0.5000.0`? Where can I find It? Is there any way to tell Pdfizer Uri is in System.Uri?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A public key token of `b77a5c561934e089` indicates that you're referencing a desktop assembly, so my bet is that Pdfizer is built only for the desktop.  There is no way to make that work in the COmpact Framework.  If you can get the source, you can try to compile it for the CF, otehrwise you'll have to ask the owners if they have a CF version.

Comment: I'm getting a similar thing while trying to use RestSharp. This code: 
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/departments/", Method.GET); 
throws the compile-time error: "The type 'System.Uri' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'" I have read elsewhere that RestSharp can be used from Windows CE clients, so I'm at an impasse...

Comment: The System assembly I'm referencing is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.dll. Runtime Version == v2.0.50727, Version == 3.5.0.0

Comment: *All* assemblies must reference the CF.  All third-party assemblies, DLLs, etc must have been built referencing the CF as well.

Comment: So now I'm wondering if RestSharp is really a viable option for accessing WebAPI methods from my CE app; HttpClient is not available until .NET 4.5, so I'm between a petrified dirt clod and an unyielding place now...

Comment: Yes, you just need the CF-compiled RestSharp assembly.  I know it exists, as I've built one myself.

Comment: How could I acquire, or build, such a beast myself?

Comment: I already have the RestSharp assembly (104.2.0.0) that I acquired via NuGet referenced in my VS 2008/CE project.

When I try to open the file from your link, RestSharp-104.2's RestSharp.sln, in VS 2008, I get, "The selected file is a solution file, but was created by a newer version of this application and cannot be opened."